# Which components are needed for new AMP site?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I need to create a new website to showcase some products.
I haven't made one with `amp-html` so I want to try it.
I did some reading and testing and got some questions I can't find the answers for.

I want to make a new page for each product. This means I duplicate the sidenav and my footer. When I add a new product/page I need to change all pages. Is that a common approach? Or can I put the content in a `json` file and use `amp-list` and/or `amp-bind`? Or should I create a script which will update the sidenav html before publishing? Something that `Dreamweaver` use to do.

Is creating a new page for each product a good idea or is another approach better? I've seen videos in which the user swipes the page aside, how does that work?

Any pointers to more documentation (written or video) will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I`ll try to answer your questions.

Q1 - I want to make a new page for each product... Is that a common approach? Or can I put the content in a json file and use amp-list and/or amp-bind?

### A - Yes, you can and should use a dynamic aprouch for your content, in this case, use JSON file to store the data and 'amp-list' / 'amp-bind' to render it.

Q2 - I've seen videos in which the user swipes the page aside, how does that work?

### A - I'd advice you to start doing basic scripts at first, and get used to it before doing some advanced tricks like swipe, but if you are really on it, I'd recomend http://idangero.us/swiper/

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'll start with a basic website. 
One question about the dynamic sidenav. Will it be crawled correctly or do I need to create a sitemap.xml for the Googlebot to index all pages of my site?